# Extract HTTP from string

Tags: c#, .net

Following line is from a webpage read, i am extracting urls of our site from the pages. I can extract most, however some of them look like the one below.

"javascript:outside('http://www.xyz.com/graduation.html')";

I want to be able to extract the link starting with http://.......

tried regex and split string but cant get it right.
Thanks

Comment: Edit the question and add everything you tried.

Comment: Given that the "above string" contains `graduation.html` but you're looking to extract `help.html`, this one's tricky. Assuming a typo, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Easily done with Regex.

```
(?<=javascript:outside\(\')http://[^']*(?=\'\))
```

... like so:

```
var src="javascript:outside('http://www.xyz.com/graduation.html')";
var match=Regex.Match(src,@"(?<=javascript:outside\(\')http://[^']*(?=\'\))");
if(match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Comment: Not saying this answer is incorrect, but as someone not super familiar with RegEx, how would implement this in C#?

Comment: James, the above is C#.  Just make sure you import System.Text.RegularExpressions.  You could shorten it by just writing
`if (Regex.Match(...).Success) {...}`

Comment: This doesn't help because in some instances it string containing is different than the one I listed as example. What I am looking for regex expression that says to get everything from http:// to the end.

Comment: @user1108282 : So how about altering your question so that you have a precise specification rather than allowing people to waste time guessing what you mean?